# Remove Icon Gloss in itunesconnect for App Store (not in app)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

Since the 1024x1024 pixel update in iTunesconnect we've been trying to remove the icon gloss from the App Store icon.

Our app icon looks fine on iPhone or iPad (prerendered icon flag is OK), but the icon we upload to itunesconnect gets the gloss added. This is what we mean: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734172/gluddle-itc.png

We already experienced this with our lite version: the icons on iOS look fine, but there does not seem to be a way to disable gloss for the App Store icons.

Does anyone have an idea how to disable gloss for the App Store as well or is this changed in the App Store update?

[we used the search, but haven't found an answer to this question]

Comment: Is the gloss appearing in the app store or just iTunes connect?

Comment: YOU CANNOT... This is all I can say

Comment: Too bad...we think some icons look better without it. (compare http://get.gluddle.com with http://getlite.gluddle.com). Thanks for your replies!

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

The App Store icon is styled according to your application info.plist. Apple use the 'gloss' effect by default in iTunes Connect because your binary hasn't been upload and processed yet. Once your app goes live you icon **should** be displayed correctly (according to your info.plist). If you still have issues your only course of action is to raise it as a bug with Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: OK, we'll try that but it didn't work for our lite version. Icon already includes gloss effects is set to YES. Let's hope that works and that the lite version gloss was a temporary bug or something...Thanks!

Comment: I recently released my app and although the icon in iTunes is correctly showing no gloss as specified in the plist, the icon in iTunesConnect is still glossy. Very odd, but i'm glad it's as intended for the public audience!

Answer (score 2):

After adding a new version of my app (with 1024 high res icon) it was also adding the gloss effect in iTunes Connect, it stayed there till I released it. It's showing fine in the AppStore and on iPhone and iPad.